# How create bar graph using array[] or from sqlite

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, bar-chart

I have this example but I want populate it dynamic from sqlite o with arraylist

```
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);


    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(44f, 0));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(88f, 1));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(66f, 2));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "datos");

    ArrayList<String> theDates = new ArrayList<>();
    theDates.add("Enero");
    theDates.add("Febrero");
    theDates.add("Marzo");

    BarData theData = new BarData(theDates, barDataSet);
    barChart.setData(theData);

    barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone help me create a bar chart with 2 column data from sqlite?

Comment: Do you have a problem with making a bargraph from an array or with gettting an array from SQLite?

Comment: From array like this: private float[] yData = { 5, 10, 15, 30, 40 };
    //private String[] xData = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" };  it'll work for me